"unpacking" binary into floating point
I've got a data set that is in binary, and trying to convert it to decimal/float.
For now, I am just using Python to get the understanding for now.
Typically, I would achieve this in one of two ways.  Either using Python's struct, or bit shifting and OR'ing.
For instance, I have a two byte array of [67,1] (little endian).
I can do this:
print(struct.unpack('<H', bytes(byte_array))[0])
or this:
byte_array[1] << 8 | byte_array[0]
Both give me the same value, 323. Which is correct.
Now, I also have a vendor provided application that reads the same raw data file that I am reading, but they represent their value differently:

What are they doing to take a 16-bit value and make a float out of with that kind of precision?
Likewise, the second value shown is -4.56, but when I do the above code I just get -5.

16 bit float?

Or simply a 16-bit int divided by 100.  We'd have to see the raw data bytes that correspond to those decimal values to even guess at the actual encoding.

The data bytes are what I showed you.  [67, 1]. Those are straight from the data file.

how does that read in binary?

@matszwecja The file is binary (as opposed to text).  The values are not.  So, 67 is represented as a capital C and 1 is represented as a "SOH".

What are the 6 bytes that result in 323.01, -4.56 and 1.32? You can upload your file to https://hexed.it/ to get the binary representation if you are on Windows and don't have the tools.

@matszwecja I'm not sure how to convert to 16 bit floating point, but I am doing some reading. Thanks.

@MarkSetchell I can't say I have the screenshot data handy, but an example is: "0x43 0x01 0xFB 0xFF 0x02 0x00"  Those 6 bytes represent those 3 values.

Treating them as int16 gives very close results np.frombuffer(b'\x43\x01', dtype=np.int16, count=1) gives 323. Unpacking structs with h format should be same.

@jgauthier are you sure that app takes exactly same raw data and/or there is no additional info encoded in that file?

Wild guess but maybe there is some kind of factor/offset added on the application side that transforms integer input into float data?

Are you able to manipulate the file systematically and see what the application returns?

The second one is 1111 1011 1111 1111 in binary representation. While this is natural as a negative integer, it doesn't look like a float. Perhaps this is a moving average?

My suggestion would be to contact the manufacturer who must surely know what they did and should be supporting their products.

Treating them as int16 is very close. There must be some other info in the file:
from struct import unpack

unpack('hhh', b'\x43\x01\xFB\xFF\x02\x00')

Yields:
(323, -5, 2)


The chances of my being this close but wrong are roughly about 1 in 655366553565536
